# Quick Setting through UIAutomator

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I am trying to access one of the item in "Quick Settings" through uiautomator. 
I am able to open the quick setting through device.openQuickSettings(); After this, I am unable to get to a particular item for example WiFi / Airplane mode. 
Could some body help me to select an item in this quick settings?

I tried the following

```
if (new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("BRIGHTNESS")).exists())
{
    new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("BRIGHTNESS")).click();
}
```

and

```
if (new UiObject(new uiSelector().className("android.widget.GridView").description("AEROPLANE MODE")).exists())
{
    new UiObject(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.GridView").description("AEROPLANE MODE")).click();
}
```

But no success..

Thanks

---

I am to access the items using following

```
UiScrollable scroll = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true));
UiObject airplane = scroll.getChildByText(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.TextView.class.getName()), "Aeroplane mode");
```

But, could anybody help me how to decide in uiautomator on Aeroplane mode is set or not in  this Quick Settings menu?

Answer (score 1):

Did you get these texts - BRIGHTNESS , AEROPLANE MODE from uiautomatorviewer?

Check screenshot here of uiautomatorviewer from my Nexus 4 device -

[image]

Here it clearly shows 'Brightness' not 'BRIGHTNESS' so it should be used like :

```
new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Brightness")).click();
```

Same goes for 'airplane mode' as well -

```
new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Airplane mode")).click();
```

For check - you can do one thing -

**Notice that when 'Airplane Mode' is ON -> wifi shows 'WI-FI OFF' and when 'Airplane Mode' is OFF -> wifi shows just 'WI-FI'**

So you can do this -

```
//put airplane mode ON
new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Airplane mode")).click();

//add some delay
sleep(3000);    //3sec delay

//check for wifi text
if(new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Wi-Fi Off")).exists()) {
    System.out.println("Airplane Mode ON");
} else {
    System.out.println("Airplane Mode OFF");
}
```

Same you can check when airplane mode is put OFF.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it in Kotlin on my Galaxy S8 running Android 7.0.

- Used `uiautomatorviewer` to find the Airplane Mode element's properties in Quick Settings
- Noticed the `content-desc` value of the element of `Airplane,mode,Off.,Button`

[image: uiautomatorviewer screenshot]

### Enable Airplane Mode

```
private val testApp = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation())

private fun enableAirplaneMode() = apply {
  testApp.uiDevice.openQuickSettings()
  testApp.uiDevice.waitForIdle()

  var airplaneModeIcon = checkNotNull(testApp.uiDevice.findObject(By.desc("Airplane,mode,Off.,Button")))

  airplaneModeIcon.click()
}
```

### Disable Airplane Mode

```
private val testApp = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation())

private fun disableAirplaneMode() = apply {
  testApp.uiDevice.openQuickSettings()
  testApp.uiDevice.waitForIdle()

  var airplaneModeIcon = checkNotNull(testApp.uiDevice.findObject(By.desc("Airplane,mode,On.,Button")))

  airplaneModeIcon.click()
}
```