# Toggling Android Device Network During Execution of an Instrumentation Test

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

Has anyone had any luck toggling the device network in the middle of an instrumentation test? I've found some hacky outdated solutions that are no longer supported [such as this one](https://www.google.com/amp/s/letsno.wordpress.com/2016/03/29/automating-offline-scenarios-using-android-espresso/amp/).

I can't seem to find any recent answers to this problem. I'm sure this is a common testing scenario for many applications. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Interesting. I think you can change the wifi SSID which the device connects to programmatically [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8818490/3145960). However, not very familiar with how you can do that during an instrumentation test.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Hmm I wonder if there is something I can do with that option. I'll take a look.

Comment: You could structure your test using `UIAutomator` and [`openQuickSettings()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/uiautomator/UiDevice.html#openQuickSettings()), then toggling airplane mode that way. Related reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681980/quick-setting-through-uiautomator). It's not exactly the best solution, but you usually have control over the device/emulator you run your tests on.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need. I'll give it a try and update this thread with my findings. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, below is a solution that I came up with to enable/disable the network during an instrumented test. Thank you for the reference to UiAutomator Sandi!

```
fun clickAirplaneMode(instrumentation: Instrumentation, targetContext: Context) {
    UiDevice.getInstance(instrumentation).run {
        targetContext.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.settings")?.let {intent ->
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
            targetContext.startActivity(intent)
            findObject(UiSelector().textContains("Network")).clickAndWaitForNewWindow()
            findObject(UiSelector().textContains("Airplane")).click()
        }
    }
}
```